# Using streaming notifications with delegate access

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

So far all information that I read about streaming notifications says that you are expected to use impersonation with streaming subscriptions when you want to subscribe to not your mailboxes. This sounds reasonable when you have service application that accesses user mailboxes. In my case I need to subscribe to calendars of room mailboxes.

Based on this answer: [Getting notification from Resource calendar in EWS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/451cf612-07dd-4e75-a343-23051bf3a87b/getting-notification-from-resource-calendar-in-ews?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment) room mailboxes usually have their account disabled and I need to use delegation.

So what is proper way to subscribe and maintain affinity when using delegation? Should I just ignore setting the impersonation header and do everything else as described in [How to: Maintain affinity between a group of subscriptions and the Mailbox server in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458789(v=exchg.150).aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

When you creating folder object, pass the other user email address which shared his calendar with you. AS below
 folders[0] = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox("OtherUserEmail"));
And then subscribe.
service.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications

Answer (score 0):

For resource rooms I use impersonation as the preferred access.  I know that in general the AD userids for room resources are disabled for login in AD, but my guess is that affects only Windows login.  Technically when you impersonate, you don't really login as the room user.  You log in as the service account with those credentials, and then indicate with the impersonation id that you want Exchange to pretend it's actually the room making all the requests you are about to make.